# Prove set $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to the interval $(0 ; 1)$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the set $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to the interval $(0 ; 1)$, where
$B=\left\{\left(x_1, x_2\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x_2=2 x_1^2, 0<x_1<4\right\}$

**Is the proof to it -- a homeopmorphic function?**

My interpretation.(rephrasing the requirements for [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)).

Is there a map such that contracts the semiparabola $B$ to the interval (0,1), and is inverse is also bijection.

I need a overall idea of what a proof for it would look like.

Comment: You need to find a map $\varphi: (0,1) \rightarrow B$ such that $\varphi$ is a bijection, $\varphi$ is continuous and $\varphi^{-1}$ is continuous. Try to think how you can relate $B$ to the interval, then show that the map is continuous. Then compute the inverse and show that it is also continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look on the graph of the function $(x,2x^{2})$, and use the fact it is injective between $0$ to $4$, to you can "project" it onto $(0,4)$.
Now try to think why $(0,4)$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: You might want to edit $[0,4]$ to $(0,4)$ as you correctly say in the following sentence to it.

Comment: You are right. I like your nickname by the way.